# ProgressView hides on list scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `List` with a `ProgressView` and some rows. When I scroll the `List` down and up again, the `ProgressView` get hidden, I notice this bug only with a certain number of rows, for example on iPhone 13 you can reproduce this bug if you have 20 rows.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ProgressView()
            ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: cannot replicate your issue on real devices. The code 
works well for me using macos 12.2, Xcode 13.2, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Maybe it is to do with using the preview.

Comment: Don't rely on Preview in run-time scenarios, it is *just-a* preview mode (ie. limited in its capabilities). Use at least simulator or, better, real device.

Comment: I reproduced it on both simulator and a real device, as I say the number of rows depends on the device type, try to reproduce it on iPhone 13.

Comment: confirmed, I have seen this issue on the iPhone 13 simulator.

Comment: It can still be reproduced on iOS15.6 real device and Xcode13.4

Answer (score 9):

I know that it's probably too late. But I also had this problem and figured it might be caused by SwiftUI "recovering" your previously used view that (for some reason) it's now hidden.

So what I did to fix this was just adding a unique ID to my progress view, this way SwiftUI won't try to re-utilize it.

Ex:

```swift
ProgressView().id(UUID())
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, so first thing first, thank you EdYuTo for giving a correct answer. The reasoning is also correct, we are reusing "cells" to save memory.

Alternatively we could use SwiftUI.Section{} to solve this missing progressView() issue. You would basically need to put the progressView() inside the Section.