# ProgressView not showing in SwiftUI List after first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a paginated list that has a `ProgressView` as its last subview. When reaching the bottom of the list the `ProgressView` triggers a task that loads more results from the remote server and the user can continue scrolling. This works fine the first time (and sometimes the second time), however, after this, the progress view is not visible anymore.

```
struct SomeView : View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : ViewModel = ViewModel ()
    var body : some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach (0...10)
                {
                    i in Text ("\(i)")
                    .frame (maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
            if viewModel.hasMoreToLoad {
                Section {
                    ProgressView ()
                    .frame (maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .task { await viewModel.loadMore() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var hasMoreToLoad : Bool = true
    @Published var isLoading : Bool = false
    
    func loadMore ()
        isLoading = true
        async { await Task.sleep(for: Duration.milliseconds(100)) }
        isLoading = false
        hasMoreToLoad = true
    }
}
```

The same can be observed with a conditional `ProgressView` within a `List`

```
List {
    if viewModel.isLoading {
        Section {
            ProgressView()
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
    } else {
        Section {
            ForEach(0...10) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Sweeper you've clearly not read the question if you're asking for an MRP....there are two already there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProgressView hides on list scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627642/progressview-hides-on-list-scroll)

Comment: @MarekB no...that's the same solution you've already proposed would work, which didn't. Please stop with the spam. I have no idea why you're so desperate to try and mark this question as a duplicate....

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in SwiftUI about `ProgressView` inside `List` that creates undefined UI behaviour (there are several posts here on SO talking about that).

If you can't take your `ProgressView` outside your `List` (maybe you just have a UI mockup to follow) I suggest you simply create your own `ProgressView`:

```
struct CustomActivityIndicator: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false

    private var animation: Animation {
        Animation.linear(duration: 1)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image("loading")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isAnimating ? 359 : 0))
            .animation(animation, value: isAnimating)
            .onAppear {
                isAnimating = true
            }
    }
}
```

`"loading"` is the name of my loading asset, you can use the asset you want (you can even find the same asset used by the Apple activity indicator).

Now you can use it like in this simple example:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var numberOfLoading = 5 // just a fake counter to stop loading
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var model = [Int]()

    private var hasMoreToLoad: Bool {
        numberOfLoading > 0
    }

    init() {
        load()
    }

    private func load() {
        guard hasMoreToLoad, !isLoading else { return }
        isLoading = true
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: Duration.seconds(2))
            isLoading = false

            let newElements = (0...9).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0...99) }
            model.append(contentsOf: newElements)
            numberOfLoading -= 1 // let's pretend we are consuming some data source
        }
    }

    func cellDidRequestLoad(_ index: Int) {
        guard index >= model.count - 1 else { return }
        load()
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(viewModel.model.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    Text("\(viewModel.model[idx])")
                        .onAppear {
                            viewModel.cellDidRequestLoad(idx)
                        }
                }
            }

            if viewModel.isLoading {
                CustomActivityIndicator()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is duplicate question and was answered by user "EdYuTo" whose solution is working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431883/7901392

Comment: It seems like there will be some problem in your implementation. Can you share more?